# Are there any active Karaite members here?

Tags: discussion, users

I have at least one question (probably more) that I would like to ask on Mi Yodeya, regarding the practices of Karaite Judaism (having [recently discovered that they're still around](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44898/are-there-jews-not-following-the-rabbinic-laws?newsletter=1&nlcode=288497%7C962f#comment118142_44898)). Really, I would like to get answers from practicing Karaites, if possible.

Therefore, I ask -- are there any Karaites who are active on Mi Yodeya?

.....a little bit of digging uncovered [this account](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2290/a-blue-thread), but it appears that he has not participated in this site since February of this year. So, if you see this question, and practice Karaite Judaism, let me know you're here so I can ask my question(s).

<sub>[Let's be clear: this is not a witch hunt -- I don't want to kick you off the site for being Karaite, nor do I think that anyone else here feels that way. I just want to know if questions I ask about Karaite practices stand a chance of being answered by practicing Karaites.]</sub>

Comment: See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1531/759 before you ask. That said, there is no reason to wait for an active member to ask a question. The sooner you ask it, the more likely you are to get a knowledgeable reader to answer from random Google searches.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'll assume, since [How do Karaites pray?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23475/5323) was left open, that questions about Karaite religious law ("halacha"?) are on-topic; am I correct in that assumption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask away. They may turn up. (They are likely themselves to be searching for Karaite information, and therefore may appear when the question is asked.)

> Yesterday I asked two questions involving the Church of Scotland. Today we have a new user who is a minister in said church.
>   [Caleb](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1167?m=6134142#6134142).

And if the questions linger unanswered, how is that a problem?

Comment: Thanks! http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45294/5323